# Correct SearchQuery for few parameters - Elasticsearch & Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-query

I'm new in Elasticsearch. I'm trying to create search in Spring Boot application using ES and I stuck with queries in ES.

This is how my app looks like.

Model:

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "sport", type = "sport")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sport {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @Column(length = 256)
   private String name;

}
```

search method in service:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/findSportByNameAndId/{name}/{id}")
public List<Sport> findSportByNameAndId(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String id){

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchQuery("name", name)
                    .operator(AND)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO)
                    .prefixLength(3))
            .withQuery(matchQuery("id", id)
                    .operator(AND))
            .build();

    List<Sport> sports = operations.queryForList(searchQuery, Sport.class);
    return sports;
}
```

part of ES index according the model above:

```
"content": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Muay Thai"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Kickboxing"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Boxing"
    }
],
```

When I try to find something with using the `name` parameter it always stick to `id` and ignore `name`. Like This:

[image]

How `SearchQuery` should  look like to find `Sport` by `name` within `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have realized how to solve it. In this case I need to use `QueryBuilder` to specify each parameter:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/findSportByNameAndId/{name}/{id}")
public List<Sport> findSportByNameAndId(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String id){

    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", name)
                    .operator(AND)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO)
                    .prefixLength(3)
            )
            .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", id));

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(qb).build();

    List<Sport> sports = operations.queryForList(searchQuery, Sport.class);
    return sports;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically doing two searches; the first one with the name parameter and the second one (which overrides the first one) with the id. The boolean operator (in this case *AND*) is useless unless you use the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-bool-query).